# Visual Code Environment error When I open it

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing the '"' character. The existence of such a character is known to have caused the Python extension to not load. If the extension fails to load please modify your paths to remove this '"' character.

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbkl.png)

Please Help me In this

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Windows user follow below instructions:

1. Right-click the Computer icon and choose Properties, or in Windows Control Panel, choose System.
2. Choose Advanced system settings.
3. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
4. Find Path variable and double click, there are two Path variables, one is for system one is for user, you can open both for find the mistake.
5. Find and delete all quote signs.
6. Re-launch VS Code

Comment: If you accept my answer, i would appreciate. Have a good day :)